# Report Builder CTP 2.3 Installation DLL Error

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I was attempting to install [Report Builder CTP 2.3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48959) and cannot get it to install on any of three tested systems.

First system was Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter - MS Azure SQL 2016 preview image with SSDT 2016 Preview installed and Report Server SQL 2016 setup and running. This isn't server software, but all components for SQL 2016 preview and the SSRS service are present...

Second system was Windows 7 Ultimate, and third was Windows 8.1. All result in the exact same error message:

[image]

Has anyone successfully installed Report Builder CTP 2.3 and if so how did you accomplish this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution... posting for anyone else testing SQL 2016.

Do NOT supply a default SSRS Server URL during the installation process and it completes without error (Windows 2012 Datacenter and Windows 7 confirmed).

[image]

Please help MS [fix this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1884536/missing-dll-report-builder-3). Happy reporting!